# I can't run the java.file that I want

Tags: java, eclipse, file, configuration

I'm a beginner at Java and Eclipse and I will have an exam this Thursday.
I just imported those .java files on that package and project I created myself (I named the package `java_10` just as it was needed, I'm mentioning this because I don't know if this is going to be useful information or not).

The problem I have is that when I click run in Eclipse, it doesn't run the current opened file but it runs another file, like in this case the `KalkulimiB.java` (as you can see, the result that is showing down on the console "`z=15`" is definitely not coming from `Bank.java`).

It didn't work at all in the beginning when I imported the files so I messed up a little with the run configurations so here's the picture how it looks like at the moment. Please zoom it up as it's needed, Please don't flag the question as a repost or something, I really searched for this problem but the solutions just didn't work or they just didn't really ask the same exact question as I am. [image: The screenshot]

Comment: Does the file that you're trying to run contain a method that starts `public static void main(String[] `?

Comment: You can check if there is any class with main function right click run

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem
yeah they do, lot's of them actually

Comment: @Gursheesh Singh 
So what should I do then? Should I just leave one main or make them all mains? The files are not connected to each other, they're separate exercises at school.

Comment: There would be main function, which you have to identify as the start of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files which can be run are those with

```
public static void main(Strings[] args){
   //code to be run
}
```

other classes cannot be run but their methods can be run inside the main function of another file. Be careful though, if there are multiple main files open then the compiler will almost always run the main file that was run last.

Answer (score 1):

Launch configurations are a bit with a mind of their own until you know Eclipse better.

You can always explicitly run a specific class by right-clicking it in the Navigator and choose "Run" (or "Debug").

Comment: Can you please provide me with a screenshot? I opened the navigator from Windwos->Show->Navigator and I right-clicked on the file I wanted to run, I went dont to Run As and Debug As but some files still had the only options they showed after either "Run Configurations" or "Debug Configurations" . Although it worked on some files though.

Comment: You can only run classes that have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: Choose the "Java Application" option on the "Run As" submenu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer although it looked like I just needed a better understanding of classes.

Comment: @AlbosHajdari If the "main-method-needed-to-run"-concept is unfamiliar to you you probably need to read up on some of the basics.  The Oracle Java tutorial is quite nice. This particular thing is covered in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html